# Print 2d array by calling a function print_array with argument the 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define length 100

void print_array();

int main()
{
    int m,n,i,j;
    int A[length][length];
    printf("Give dimensions of array (up to 100x100):\ni:\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("j:\n");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
    {
        for (n=0;n<j;n++)
        {
            A[m][n]=rand()%45+1;
            printf("A[%d,%d]=%d\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
        }
    }
    print_array(i,j,A);
    return 0;
}

void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][j])
{
    printf("\n");
    int m,n;
    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
        {
            for (n=0;n<j;n++)
            {
                printf("A[%d,%d]=%d\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
            }
        }
}
```

Hello. I am trying to print a 2d array by calling a function print but when I run the program I get:

For the first `printf()` the correct values:

```
A[0,0]=25
A[0,1]=19
A[0,2]=13
A[1,0]=4
A[1,1]=17
A[1,2]=43
A[2,0]=7
A[2,1]=37
A[2,2]=20
```

But when with the 2nd `printf()` within the function call of `print_array` I get:

```
A[0,0]=25
A[0,1]=19
A[0,2]=13
A[1,0]=0
A[1,1]=0
A[1,2]=0
A[2,0]=0
A[2,1]=0
A[2,2]=0
```

Seems like I miss something with pointers... Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is C99, right?

The problem is that you're confusing the array size.

The main program has `int A[length][length]`, but then you call the function with a dynamic size for the final dimension, `A[][j]`. If `j != length`, then the function will index the array incorrectly.

I would recommend representing the array in the function call as a bare pointer to the first element, and doing the indexing manually:

```
void print_array(const int *A, size_t width, size_t height)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
  {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < width; ++j)
      printf("A[%zu][%zu] = %d\n", i, j, A[i * width + j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wooo so many answers in 1 minute! Thanks! that should work! :)

Comment: Would it be correct to apply the same print_array for a malloced 2d array? would it be something like : `void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][j*sizeof(int)])`

Comment: my wrong its `print_array(int i,int j,int **A)` since we have array of pointers pointing to 1d arrays. If i missed something plz correct me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <time.h>
#define length 100

void print_array(int i,int j,int A[length][length]);

int main()
{
    int m,n,i,j;
    int A[length][length];
    printf("Give dimensions of array (up to 100x100):\ni:\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("j:\n");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
    {   
        for (n=0;n<j;n++)
        {   
            A[m][n]=rand()%45+1;
            printf("A[%d,%d]=%d\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
        }   
    }   
    print_array(i,j,A);
    return 0;
}

void print_array(int i,int j,int A[length][length])
{
    printf("\n");
    int m,n;
    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
        {   
            for (n=0;n<j;n++)
            {   
                printf("A[%d,%d]=%d\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
            }   
        }   
}
```

Apart from the above, you need to do some input validation for the dimension (`i` and `j`). They should not exceed the `length`. If it exceeds the `length` then you will run into problems.

Comment: Yup i just removed some lines when i put the code here so that it wont get too long. Thanks again!

Comment: @GeoPapas Cool. If you find my answer useful, please feel free to upvote! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][j])
```

should be

```
void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][length])
```

When you tell the compiler that the *actual* array has different dimensions than what you earlier specified, it accesses the wrong elements. `A` is always 100x100, you just don't fill all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the size of the array `int A[][]` in the function signature. Use this function instead :

```
void print_array(int i,int j,int A[length][length])
{
    printf("\n");
    int m,n;
    for (m=0;m<i;m++)
        {
            for (n=0;n<j;n++)
            {
                printf("A[%d,%d]=%d\n",m,n,A[m][n]);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared A as int A[length][length], But in the print_array function you've declare it as A[][j] which means in your function A have a different number of colones which leads to this error.

change this line

```
void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][j])
```

with this one

```
void print_array(int i,int j,int A[][length])
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

First you should forward declare your function with the correct prototype

```
void print_array(int n,int m, int A[n][m]);
```

And then use it with the correct dimensions

```
print_array(length, length, A);
```

Other than that:

- use `size_t` for sizes instead of `int`
- usual naming conventions have `i` and `j` as indices and `n` and `m`
  as sizes. Sticking to such conventions makes code easier to read for others.

Answer (score 0):

array and matrix printing functions are little similar but tricky..
but i have worked on it and found out some thing and i think it will be useful for all
here is a simple C code for Function for printing matrix

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printmatrix(int l,int x,int y,int *p_arr);
void putvalue(int l,int x,int y,int *r_arr);
/*  ******** Function to insert some random value in to a Matrix ************ */
void putvalue(int l,int x,int y,int *r_arr)
{
  int i,j;
  for(i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        r_arr[(l*i)+j]=i+j+10;
    }
  }
}
/* *********Function to Print any Matrix ********** */
void printmatrix(int l,int x, int y,int *p_arr)
{
  int i,j;
  printf("\n");
  for(i=0;i<x;i++)
  {
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d",p_arr[(l*i)+j]);
    }
  }
}
/* ****** Main ****** */
void main()
{
  int i,j,l;
  int Big_arr[80][100],Small_arr[20][40];   

     //  ****** I have taken two different size arrays  *****

  int x,y;
  clrscr();
  printf("\n Enter x and y values under 20X40:"); // Because of screen size of Output
  scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
  if((x!=0)&&(y!=0))
  {
    printf("\n %dX%d",x,y);

    l=sizeof(Big_arr[0])/sizeof(Big_arr[0][0]);  // **** l is the length of a single row of matrix
    putvalue(l,x,y,(int*)Big_arr);
    printf("\n Printing Big_arr");
    printmatrix(l,x,y,(int*)Big_arr);


    l=sizeof(Small_arr[0])/sizeof(Small_arr[0][0]);
    putvalue(l,x,y,(int*)Small_arr);
    printf("\n Printing Small_arr");
    printmatrix(l,x,y,(int*)Small_arr);
  }
  else
    printf("\n ***** Enter valied x and y values *****");
  getch();

}
```

hope u like it.