# Passing two dimensional array in a function as parameter

Tags: arrays, c, function, 2d

```
#include<stdio.h>

void print(int r, int c, int Ar[][c])
{
    int i,j;
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%d ",Ar[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
  int m,n,i,j;
  int A[100][100];
 
  printf("Enter number of rows and columns matrix: ");
  scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
  printf("Enter elements of first matrix:\n");
  for (i=0;i<m;i++)
  {
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    scanf("%d",&A[i][j]);
  }
  print(m,n,A);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:
Enter number of rows and columns matrix:2 3
Enter elements of first matrix:
2 1 3
5 4 6

2 1 3
0 0 0

Why it's not printing the second line ?

Comment: Try changing `Ar[][c]` to `Ar[][100]`

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Please check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715034/print-2d-array-by-calling-a-function-print-array-with-argument-the-2d-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print 2d array by calling a function print\_array with argument the 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715034/print-2d-array-by-calling-a-function-print-array-with-argument-the-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This question was tagged C++ before . . .

---

If you want to pass a plain old C-array to a function, you have 2 possibilities.

1. Pass by reference
2. Pass by pointer

What you used, does not even compile.

In C++ arrays must have a compile-time-known size.

Please see:

```
void function1(int(&m)[3][4])   // For passing array by reference
{}
void function2(int(*m)[3][4])   // For passing array by pointer
{}

int main()
{
    int matrix[3][4]; // Define 2 dimensional array

    function1(matrix);  // Call by reference
    function2(&matrix); // Call via pointer 
    return 0;
}
```

In any case. Usage of modern c++ containers like `std::array` or `std::vector` are nearly always the by far better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following program works only if your compiler is C99 compatible.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
// n must be passed before the 2D array
void print(int m, int n, int arr[][n])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
}
 
int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    int m = 3, n = 3;
    print(m, n, arr);
    return 0;
}
```